# Let's [bypass] usage of this tag

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

I saw the [bypass](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bypass) tag a few moments ago. I think it is redundant. It has no tag wiki.

I saw it when a question was asking how to bypass school controls. The tag seemed totally useless in that question.

##### Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

What do you want to bypass? The [title word filter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112944/the-title-word-filter-is-one-of-the-worst-ideas-ever-implemented-on-so), your antivirus software, or parental controls?

##### Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Bypassing stuff in programming languages is off topic. It's so ambiguous I don't know what it means.
Here's some even more ridiculous stuff:

- Bypassing a bridge without making sound? You gotta be kidding!
- Bypassing a `<div>` tag using JavaScript? Belongs on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com).

##### Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

No. `Bypassing stuff` is unclear.

##### Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

No.

- You want to bypass a train station? Sure.
- Want to bypass a software restriction with code? Off-topic.
- Want to bypass antivirus? Uninstall it!

**Burninate it!**

Answer (score 1):

I think the [bypass] tag should be kept for "bypassing parental controls or school computer restrictions". The term "bypass" by itself is often used by kids and teens asking how to bypass parental controls, and it's a commonly-asked question which is on topic for Super User, which is about asking for help with using computer software or hardware. Most of the time, no code needs to be written to bypass such restrictions, thus making Stack Overflow unnecessary for this type of question.